# POST Fetch .Net Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs, asp.net-core, .net-core

question.
I am having an issue when doing fetch post going to controller,
fetch get is working fine, only the post the value is always null. But when I am using a postman it's working fine.
Hope someone can help

//JS Side

```
var url = 'Test/SaveReportDetail';
var data = { username: 'example' };

fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
    body: JSON.stringify(data), // data can be `string` or {object}!
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
    }
}).then(res => res.json())
    .then(response => console.log('Success:', JSON.stringify(response)))
    .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
```

//Controller Side

```
 [HttpPost]
 public JsonResult SaveReportDetail(string username)
 {
      //var RepObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReportTemplate>(reportTemplate);
      //return "t";

      return Json("b");
  }
```

Comment: Try to change your url: `Test/SaveReportDetail` to `/Test/SaveReportDetail`

Answer (score 4):

You need to always use `[FromBody]` for data from request body,besides above answer, if you only need to pass a string, you could pass the string directly instead of wrap in an object:

```
var url = 'Test/SaveReportDetail';
var username =  'example' ;

fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
    body: JSON.stringify(username), 
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
    }
}).then(res => res.json())
    .then(response => console.log('Success:', JSON.stringify(response)))
    .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
```

Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SaveReportDetail([FromBody]string username)
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to use your actions like that. Try this. It will work.

```
    [HttpPost("SaveReportDetail")]
    public JsonResult SaveReportDetail([FromBody]SaveReportDetailInput input)
    {
        var userName = input.Username;

        return Json("b");
    }
```

Input Class example

```
    public class SaveReportDetailInput {
        public string Username { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: part of it your are correct, i did instead of using a strong type object, i just use the object as keyword.i still don't know why, happy if you can explain it... :D

Comment: take a look at the model binding docs for ASP.NET Core - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2#complex-types